# Imports in app.module.ts are not working global

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 8.0 and installed in my app the Angular Calendar component. As suggested I added to the **app.module.ts** the import of the Calendar Module, just like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    PipesModule,
    BreadcrumbModule,
    MenuModule,
    DashboardModule,
    ServicesModule,
    LoginModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot({ provide: DateAdapter, useFactory: momentAdapterFactory })
  ]
  })
```

I'm using the Calendar Component in the ServicesComponent which is declared in the ServicesModule. If I run the app I got the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'view' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("v class="btn-group">
                      <div class="btn btn-primary" mwlCalendarPreviousView [ERROR ->][view]="view" [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
```

But if I import the CalendarModule in the Services Module just like the following, it works:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ServicesAddComponent,
    ServicesListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    PipesModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot({ provide: DateAdapter, useFactory: momentAdapterFactory })
  ],
  providers: [
    ServicesService
  ],
  exports: [
    ServicesListComponent
  ]
})
```

Why the CalendarModule is not working globally considering that I made the import in app.module.ts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Angular Modules documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules#ngmodule-metadata), the components from a given module are available only in the components' templates of the module that imports it.

> imports: Other modules whose exported classes are needed by component
> templates declared in *this* NgModule.